SVG editor weird scrolling bug
Weird scrolling behavior on dragging Foreign object.
so i want to build a moodboard application in vue. Sort of like https://mydraft.cc/ where a user can have a board where he can drag certain parts of the page. I see that many applications use SVG for this. In the board users will have specific micro applications that needs extensive reactivty. There for i am using foreign objects inside of the svg.
Now its all working great except for one weird scroll behavior. as included in the added video when i drag the element down at first its working perfectly. But when i scroll down and then i drag the red square the svg scrolls down instead of only dragging the box itself down. How do i prevent the browser from scrolling and only move the box down.
if you want to see the weird behavior i recorded it here. https://www.loom.com/share/f5c7f473d0c841d692fa759c62ba4203?sid=89fedaa6-0b07-4561-a0bd-b1ef1d1f737c
At the top and bottom of the pages its behaving normally.
the code is as follows
app.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
    import CanvasComponent from "@/components/CanvasComponent.vue";

    const width = 3000;
    const height = 3000;

    window.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    })
</script>

<template>
    <div :style="`width:${(width+80)}px; height:${(height+80)}px`" class="overflow-auto p-10">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 3000 3000" style="background-color:blue" :width="width  + 'px'" :height="height  + 'px'" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
            <CanvasComponent :initial-x="300" :initial-y="400" initial-width="200px" initial-height="300px"></CanvasComponent>
        </svg>
    </div>
</template>

CanvasComponent.Vue
<script setup lang='ts'>
    import {nextTick, ref} from "vue";

    const {initialX, initialY, initialWidth, initialHeight} = defineProps<{
        initialX: number,
        initialY: number,
        initialWidth: string,
        initialHeight: string
    }>();

    const x = ref(initialX)
    const y = ref(initialY);
    const width = ref(initialWidth)
    const height = ref(initialHeight)

    const isDragging = ref(false);
    const offsetX = ref(0);
    const offsetY = ref(0);


    const dragStart = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault()

        isDragging.value = true;

        offsetX.value = e.clientX - x.value;
        offsetY.value = e.clientY - y.value;

        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; // Prevent scrolling

        nextTick(() => {
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', dragEnd);
        });
    }

    const drag = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!isDragging.value) return;
        x.value = e.clientX - offsetX.value;
        y.value = e.clientY - offsetY.value;
    }

    const dragEnd = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        isDragging.value = false;

        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', dragEnd);
    }

</script>

<template>
    <svg>
        <foreignObject class="drag-handle-class"
                       :x="x"
                       :y="y"
                       :width="width"
                       :height="height"
                       @mousedown="dragStart"
        >
            <div class="w-full h-full bg-red-500 overflow-scroll drag-handle-class"></div>
        </foreignObject>
    </svg>
</template>

I tried preventing the scolling itself but that didnt work. as you can see in the video it works perfectly in firefox its just the chromium browsers that are being weird.

Do you have a preview of your app? I am curious to try it on my side too. Also, have you tried it in regular Chrome or Edge? Might be an Arc booster interfering with your page maybe? Because I don't think that Chrome applies any kind of weird boundaries.

foreignobject inside SVG always produces unexpected behaviour to me. What happens if you replace that el with an svg element?

yes i just set up a live demo at @kissu https://canvas-ebon-gamma.vercel.app/
i have tried it on regular edge and that also has the scrolling issue. i know there is a way to fix it because other apps like the mentioned https://mydraft.cc/  also use svg and its not having that issue for them.

Hmmm changing the foreign object it to a rect fixed the issue. but i want to be able to put in a regular vue component because i need the user to be able to interact with it. Is there any way of doing this without the foreignObject? if not how do i fix the issue with the foreign object.

i wrapped another svg around the foreign object itself and now it works! no more weird scrolling!. Is there any down side of wrapping a svg inside of an svg per component im adding? ill update the code

Damn, quite surprising but nice catch! I guess that it's totally fine. It's just an empty SVG wrapper so nothing dramatic will happen to it I think. Well played!
